# PyPy reload(...) error

Tags: python, pypy

I'm going throgh Segaran's *Programming Collective Intelligence* using Windows version of PyPy.

The author is gradually building [this](http://csrc.tamu-commerce.edu/projs/colint/browser/src/colint/ch02/recommendations.py?rev=1) example. First loading the dictionary with:

```
from recommendations import critics
```

*recommendations.py* is then modified by adding a new function. The reader is then supposed to reload the module with:

```
reload(recommendations)
```

Instead of successful reload I get this error instead:

```
>>>> reload(recommendations)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: global name 'recommendations' is not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global is not there. You need to import recommendations for it to work.